# Cannot add Expires headers in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-expires, expires-header

Been trying to get rid of the "Add Expires headers" in GTmatrix, with no success. I've installed the WP Fastest Cache plugin and tried a bunch of different variations to .htaccess that I found on stackoverflow and some other websites where people had similar questions, with no success - GTmatrix still shows the same error.

This is my current .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WpFastestCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
# Start WPFC Exclude
# End WPFC Exclude
# Start_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !wordpress_logged_in_[^\=]+\=username
# End_WPFC_Exclude_Admin_Cookie
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit|Twitterbot|LinkedInBot|WhatsApp|Mediatoolkitbot)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(WP\sFastest\sCache\sPreload(\siPhone\sMobile)?\s*Bot)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/){2}$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.+
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !comment_author_
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !woocommerce_items_in_cart
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !safirmobilswitcher=mobil
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile} !^[a-z0-9\"]+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f [or]
RewriteCond /home/user/public_html/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) "/wp-content/cache/all/$1/index.html" [L]
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "index\.(html|htm)$">
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Mon, 29 Oct 1923 20:30:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END WpFastestCache
#Customize expires cache start - adjust the period according to your needs
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  FileETag MTime Size
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain text/html text/xml text/css application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/javascript application/x-javascript
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType text/html "access 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"  
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
  ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
#Expires cache end
# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
      Header append Cache-Control "public"  
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
      Header append Cache-Control "public"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
      Header append Cache-Control "private"
    </filesMatch>
    <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
      Header append Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
    </filesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# LBROWSERCSTART Browser Caching
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/xhtml-xml "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
# END Caching LBROWSERCEND


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check `mod_expires` module is enabled on your server’s main configuration file

You can check this with your hosting provider or if you have access to the `httpd.conf` file the following line should be un-commented so expires headers works:

```
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
```

Or It may chances that problem associated with your plugin. You can check with trying this lightweight [plugin for adding expires headers.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-expires-headers/) It may not serve your whole purpose but help to find out that your plugin working fine or not.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the following steps: 
First checked my apache site configuration and make sure AllowOverride all present like below.

```
<Directory /var/www/mysite>
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

Then tried the following commands:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo a2enmod headers 
sudo a2enmod expires
sudo service apache2 restart
```